# uTorrent .. How to Set Order in " Prioritize by file order "..?

Tags: download, tv, utorrent, serial

This is cool feature to download TV serial.... 
But but i want to know how to set order ? If original order is wrong then ?
When you use feature " Prioritize by file order " then utorrent downloads files one by one .. But what if that order is wrong ? many times this order is highly randon .. so it start from random 23 rd episode then 12 th episode then 1st episode .. So my Q is how to set order for this " Prioritize by file order " feature ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which GUI are you using,if it's a windows, linux version etc.. but normally you select priority as "high", "normal", "low" and "skip". I do it all the time for forcing the first episodes to be downloaded first.

In both windows and ubuntu versions I'm certain that under the "files" tab you can double click on the file to switch between priorities or by right-clicking on the file (also on the "files" tab) you can select prio directly